# Windows 2008 R2 Failover Cluster FTP with IIS 7.5 (0x80070490 Element Not Found)

Tags: ftp, iis-7.5, failover

I setup a Failover FTP using a script service/application on our 3 node cluster.  I have followed the following guide which seems to be fairly complete: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/974603

However the FTP site I've added which is linked to the storage for that service will not start.  I get the following error: 0x80070490 Element Not Found.  I think it may be related to this kbb, but I'm not sure:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2720218

Failing over/moving the service around the 3 nodes seems to work fine (except the FTP doesn't start, and starting it manually fails).  The IP, computer name, and 2 mount points for storage get moved successfully.  The only way I can get it to start is to go into IIS on the owning node, remove the FTP site and set it up again.  As soon as I fail it over to another node however, I'm back to the error.

I believe it has something to do with IIS not seeing the storage despite it being available.  I've made the storage a prerequisite for the script so the storage must be online before the script tries to start the FTP site.  Nevertheless, it doesn't work.

Summary:  Windows 2008 R2 Cluster FTP Server is set to broadcast on the service IP.  It's root directory is the a root drive of assigned storage in the cluster service.  The other storage is a MP mounted underneath this drive.  FTP site works fine on initial setup but fails when failing over with Element Not Found error. Seems to be related to disk not being available despite it existing as if you go to of of the other nodes without the disks, the FTP site in IIS has the red 'X' on it and attempting to start it gives the same error.

Comment: Please contact Microsoft support via http://support.microsoft.com. I personally think the script in that KB article was only provided for web sites, so FTP sites were not considered. Microsoft support might provide you a revised script to support FTP sites as well.

Comment: At the very to of the script it says: 'This script provides high availability for IIS FTP websites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was my fault for not setting up Offline files.  Once I completed that it worked.  Offline files requires two server restarts and I didn't want to go through that process without testing how the Clustered FTP would work (this Cluster is in Production use).  Unfortunately, once the share hosting the IIS shared configuration goes offline it will NOT come back online until you recycle the Microsoft FTP Service (which is why offline files is required).  I could have modified the script to perform a recycle in the StartFTPSVC function (instead of just checking if it was started and if not starting it).